# Passing parameters between local and remote jenkins jobs

Tags: jenkins, groovy, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins

Im Trying to do the following:

Job X (Jenkins Job) on server A running a Groovy script and the output of that script is a string.
My goal is to pass this string to job Y (Jenkins Job) on server B.

What is the best way to pass this string to a remote Jenkins Job?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use any one of the two options:

[Option 1: Remote Trigger Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Remote+Trigger+Plugin)

[image]

[Option 2: Using API](http://www.tothenew.com/blog/jenkins-api-integration-trigger-job-remotely/)

```
 curl -v -X POST jenkins_url/job/job_name/buildWithParameters

--data token=your_token

--user jenkins_user_email:jenkins_user_password

--data-urlencode json= '{"parameter1":"value1", "parameter2":"value2"}'
```